# How do I create a Django ModelForm, so that it's fields are sometimes required, sometimes not?

Tags: python, django, modelform

Ok, here is the question.
Imagine I have a ModelForm which have only two fields. like this one:

```
class ColorForm(forms.Form):
    color_by_name = forms.CharField()
    color = forms.IntegerField(widget = forms.Select(choices=COLOR_CHOICES))
```

So a user can either input a color name, a choose it from a list. Color is required, but that doesn't mean, that user should enter it manually. There do I put validation, so that my code checks if user selected color in dropdownlist and if not then he should write it manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make them both `required=False`, but write a `clean()` method which checks for one or the other. See [the validation documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for an example.